# How to keep GNU Indent from formatting comments?

Tags: text-formatting, indentation

I don't want that GNU Indent to touch any comment whatsoever. But it seems that there is no option that allows me to keep the comments untouched.

What commands or commands combination should I use to keep the comments in the code unmodified by indent.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/indent/manual/html_section/indent_6.html#SEC8) boxed comments are not indented. There are some additional switch options of non-boxed comments.

Comment: I'm having problems with the non-boxed comments. Those that are at the right of the code. And I've tried lots of combinations so far and I just can't keep indent from formatting the comments. I've also tried to not to include any comment-related command without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation states -`nfca` tells gnu-indent to not format any comments.

Comment: Doesn't seem to have any effect, at least in indent 2.2.12